# NSSavePanel can't change file name

Tags: objective-c, macos, nssavepanel

In my mac app I'm using `NSSavePanel` - but it's behaving very strange. Sometimes I can't change the default name of the file.

I'm using it like this:

```
NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
[savePanel setAllowedFileTypes:@[@"jpg"]];
[savePanel setLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()];

if([savePanel runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
{
    //saving file
}
```

I can't find why sometimes it lets me change the file name and other times no, I can save a file but a changing name in save panel is blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried providing a default name?

```
[savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:@"New File.txt"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper answer, but may shed some light on the issue (which I'm struggling with as well).

What I have found so far, is that if you **do not have an active window** when you call

```
result = panel.runModal() // swift
NSModalResponse result = [panel runModal]; // Obj-C
```

Then the behavior of `NSSavePanel` is broken, and although you can click in the name field you can't type there (beeps if you try).

I also found an **ugly little workaround**. If you allow creating new directories,

```
    panel.canCreateDirectories = YES;  // Obj-C
```

and press the button in the save panel to do this - a small sheet (yet another window...) appears on top of the `NSSavePanel` and if you cancel and dismiss this sheet - you regain ability to type in the name field.

Since OP did not provide any description of the programmatic scenario and environment for his issue, but it seems related since forcing the window-level to be "modal" fixed the issue for him.

In my case (I'm opening `NSSavePanel` from a menu-bar item **pop-over window**. Alas the popover closes BEFORE my NSSavePanel manages "to attach to it". Manually setting the level

```
panel.level = NSWindow.Level.modalPanel // Swift
panel.level = NSModalPanelWindowLevel;  // Obj-C
```

did NOT help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let panel = NSSavePanel()
panel.nameFieldStringValue = "filename.txt" // <-- user editable prompt 

if panel.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK, let url = panel.url {
    // use url path here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so strange but I would like to share my solution. As `@Rupert Pupkin` described, I already used `nameFieldStringValue` but there was strange behaviour of `NSSavePanel`, it was not changing the name sometimes, and sometimes was changing. So I see I did not describe level of my `NSSavePanel`

```
savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "YourFileName"
savePanel.level = NSWindow.Level.modalPanel
```

This two lines of code with together worked for me.

My current NSSavePanel code is like that:

```
let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
savePanel.title = "Download File"
savePanel.prompt = "Download"
savePanel.message = "Choose a directory to save your scanned document"
savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "myfile"
savePanel.level = NSWindow.Level.modalPanel

savePanel.showsTagField = false
savePanel.isExtensionHidden = false
savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Didn't help in my case.